# Java webservice client, change client certificate dynamically

Tags: java, web-services, certificate, keystore

I hava the following problem. I have a webservice, which has endpoints that can be called over SSL, and some that can only be called by also using a client certificate to authenticate the client. The problem is that I want to dynamically change the client side certificate.
My code is:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
//...
// first web service call, without client side certificate -> OK
//...
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystore1.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
//...
// second web service call
```

My problem is at the second call. Here I get an Exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

If I run only the second part of the code everything is fine, it works perfectly (so I do have the *keystore.jks* with the client certificate, and the server does authenticate my request correctly). What am I doing wrong? How can I dynamically change the client side certificate when calling webservices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suspect is happening is that you're using some method which is using the default JSSE `SSLContext` for its SSL socket factory. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization) it appears that the SSL context only gets configured once, when it is first created, and setting the system properties after its first use has no effect.

I'd recommend the use of Apache HttpClient. Their [SSLSocketFactory](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) implementation allows programmatic customization of the keystore and truststore to use for connections made with that factory. On top of that, HttpClient gives you a whole lot more features and configuration options than anything you get out of the box with the JDK.

Comment: I tried to use their SSLSocketFactory, but it is not compatible with `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`. I get a `ClassCastException`:
`org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`
What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: @hpityu What library are you using to make the web service call? You won't be able to just drop in an Apache `SSLSocketFactory` instance to somewhere that is expecting `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`. It's designed for use with the `HttpClient` provided by Apache. Depending on your application, you might be able to (1) rewrite your client code to use `HttpClient`, or (2) write an adapter to wrap the Apache `SSLSocketFactory` to implement `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`.